# How to write a mutator method in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
Array.prototype.clear = function(){
    this = new Array();
    return true;
}
```

That code raise an `invalid assignment left-hand side` error.

How do I change the object itself within one of his methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't change the reference of what the [`this` value](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-10.1.7) points to, it is immutable.

If you want to *clear* the current array, you can simply set its `length` property to zero:

```
Array.prototype.clear = function(){
  this.length = 0;
  return true;
};
```

**Edit:** Looking at the comment made to the sasuke's answer, you could empty the array as in my first example, and then `push` the elements of another array, for example:

```
Array.prototype.test = function () {
  var newArray = ['foo', 'bar']; // new array elements
  this.length = 0; // empty original
  this.push.apply(this, newArray); // push elements of new array
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure who down-voted you but your post was more informative than mine; esp the immutability of `this` part. +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
Array.prototype.clear = function(){
    this.length = 0;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What if I want my array equals `['this array has been cleared']` after the method runs?

Comment: @Erik, you can always check an array's length property. There should really be no need for a 'isCleared' state.